# Reuse superclass static fields

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have this class declaration

```
abstract class  A {
    protected static String message = "Hello";
}
```

And I want this field to get propagated to subclasses, to avoid typing `protected static String message = "Whatever";` (the value of this static field is different in each subclass) in all the subclasses.

I know this won't work:

```
class B extends A {

    static {
        message = "Blablabla";
    }
}
```

Because it will actually modify `A`'s `message` because static fields/methods are not inherited. What I want to know is if there's any other way of doing this, or if I have to rewrite the static field on each subclass.

Comment: What keeps you from writing a non-static `protected String getMessage()` template method (which can be abstract or concrete in `A`, depending on whether you want to allow for a default behaviour)

Comment: What kind of solution are you expecting if you want it to be shorter than 4 words?

Comment: It's not about 4 words. It's about code reuse, which -supposedly- is one of the benefits of using OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do it.

You may consider use some utility class which maps a Class object to a message. This will help you use general methods to work with messages based on `this.getClass()`.

Comment: The question is an example. I have several fields on the base class. So it's still the same problem because I would need to define a class that holds these fields to map it to a `Class` instance, which returns me to starting point problem. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @m0skit0 Of course, you'll need more coding. To make it look like your example with static section you can use something like `register(B.class, "Whatever")` in this section of any class. On the other hand, the pros of this method include storing only one reference for every class (instead of storing a reference for every object in case of other suggestions).

Comment: Yes, but as I said, probably the second argument ("Whatever") has to be a whole object, and not only a String one, so I go back to the problem of static inheritance again :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by going back to the problem of static inheritance again. My approach doesn't use inheritance at all. As example, when you want to assign a message for a class, you use `register`, when you want to get a message for a class, you just use `getMessage`. These methods are defined in another helper class which doesn't use inheritance, it's just a map from a class to a message. Besides, this class is a singleton.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using a protected method getMessage() that gets overridden by each subclass instead of a static field.

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected String getMessage() {
        return "Blablabla";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I really don't like using hardcoded string inside methods, this answer basically is the same answer as Keppil's (check the comments I made there).

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a get method in this case:

```
abstract class  A {
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello";
    protected String getMessage() {
        return DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    }
}
```

That makes it easy to override the message in subclasses where I want to.

Comment: Thanks but solves nothing actually because this way I still have to write `private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Whatever";` in all subclasses, which is the main problem.

Comment: @m0skit0: No you don't, why would you?

Comment: Huh? As I stated, I want a different `DEFAULT_MESSAGE` value in each subclass.

Comment: @m0skit0: Ok, then you need to override `getMessage()` in each subclass where you want it changed. The static default message was just a style choice, you can skip that line and write the message directly if you prefer.

Comment: I actually like your style more, but as I can see, there's really no satisfactory solution using static fields. I will go with instance fields then. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Static fields and methods *are* inherited - as a C programmer, I was told to think of them as being similar to "global" variables, namespaced to the class (and with private/protected restrictions).

From your first snippet, `B.message` will be "Hello".

You have to make it either

```
public class A {
  protected String message = "Hello";
}
```

or

```
public class A {
  private static String message = "Hello";
}

public class B {
  private static String message = "Howdy";
}
```

Comment: This is not useful since as I said in the OP, I don't want to rewrite the field declaration in all subclasses. The first snippet also doesn't work since I would have to initialize all objects, and IMHO this is useless work since I already know all instances of that class will have such value. And I think Java static fields/methods are technically not inherited but **visible** since you if I do `B.A` I'm actually referring to `A.A`.

Comment: That said, and looking that there are no useful ways of doing this as static fields, I will probably use your first example and override the value in the subclass constructor. Thanks!

Comment: A.A => B.A _is_ inheritance.  It's funny, sometimes we go to all this effort to save a little bit of effort, just out of principal - you need to step back sometimes and put it in perspective.  The 2nd snippet is a common pattern - you'll have similar lines at the start of every class eg: "private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyClass.class );"

Comment: Yes, but being common doesn't mean it's good ;) I also have that kind of Logger thing, but don't you think it would be way easier, cleaner and more usable if you could inherit this static final Logger from a superclass?

Comment: But then you'd only have one logger instance in your app and it would be a lot harder to figure out which class was writing each log event.

Comment: Looks like you didn't understand my question in the first place. You're right, that's how it works in Java, **but** that's not what I want to do or what I'm asking. My intention is not having one logger, but rather have the static instance of a superclass propagate through subclasses in *real* inheritance, that is, copied field in the subclass, not visible field of the superclass (like non-static fields). Hope I made my point clear now.

Comment: I think you need to get the definition of static clear  in your head. A static field means that the single instance is shared by all instances of the class, and if it is not private, the same instance will be shared by all instances of all subclasses. Sorry, but you can't have your cake and eat it too.  Either you have a shared (protected/public) static field which has the same value (the same instance), a private static field (unfortunately) duplicated in each class, or a protected non-static field in the super class.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know what is static/non-static and how it works, as I already stated in my question. I want to know which alternatives there are about this, if there's another mechanism/alternative I don't know about for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Would an aspect let you achieve what you want to do?  From one place you could configure/manage the return value for a method with a specific nam, on a class-by- class basis.  ...it would still be more work than duplicating the same boiler plate "private static ..." in each subclass.

Comment: Can you please expand this answer? I don't fully understand what you mean. What I understand is something like tcb's answer.